# How can I change the Delay before triggering the OnKeyDown-Event after it was triggered once in Delphi/FMX?

Tags: delphi, delay, firemonkey, keydown

I'm sorry, but it seems like I have a beginner problem again, but i didn't found a solution to it online or in the help section:

I want to use the OnKeyDown Event to do something (Different things, so i need a general solution), as Example to increase a number in a label.
My code for this would look the following:

```
Var i : Integer = 0;
... 
procedure TExampleForm.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);


begin
  Inc(i);
  ExampleLabel.Text:=IntToStr(i);
end;
```

If i press and hold a Key in the actual program, it will trigger the event just once immediately, and then it will trigger the event after a short delay many times, exactly how it should: The problem is, that i dont want this delay after the first trigger of the event and these, which are caused by the holding of the button. Is there any way to stop Delphi (Or probablly the Keyboard) from behaving like this? I would really appreciate a solution, thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Increase the label using a timer. Enable/disable the timer according to key down and key up events.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand I will try this, maybe that will work - but unfortunately this will be a huge amount of code, is there no other way to get around this problem? Thanks anyways

Comment: H.: It will be very little code.

Comment: Notice that the code in your question contains bug. A non-reference counted local variable, like `i`, will be uninitialized. It will not start on `0` (unless by coincidence, which might vary from time to time you run the function).

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand Thanks, it was just an example of what i mean, i dont actually use this code, but you're right, this would cause an error I think, thanks

Comment: Actually this is an operating system setting. It is a feature, that users have asked for wayyyyy back. It is called repeat delay. Changing the OSs behavior in your application might cause irritation with your users, unless of course pressing that key is not used for editing text but something else, like steering something via WASD.

Comment: @sherlock70 Yeah, i think that would be a really great feature, as this might be a problem to anyone who doesn't want to code just the standard things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Firemonkey myself, but the following VCL demo should be trivial to convert to Firemonkey should you want to.

1. Drop a `TLabel` on the form.
2. Drop a `TTimer` on the form. Set its `Interval` to `30` and `Enabled` to `False`. In its `OnTimer` event, write something like

   ```
   procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Label1.Tag := Label1.Tag + 1;
     Label1.Caption := Label1.Tag.ToString;
   end;
   ```
3. In the form's `OnKeyDown` handler, write

   ```
   procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
     Shift: TShiftState);
   begin
     if Key = VK_SPACE then
       Timer1.Enabled := true;
   end;
   ```
4. In the form's `OnKeyUp` handler, write

   ```
   procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
   begin
     if Key = VK_SPACE then
       Timer1.Enabled := false;
   end;
   ```